# Issue with Google Chrome twilio video chat

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, video, twilio

In Firefox video chat workings fine but Media device is not activated in Google Chrome.
Code:

**local.php**

```
<div id="remote" style="display:inline-block;"></div>
<div id="local" style="display:inline-block;"></div>
<script src="https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/common/v0.1/twilio-common.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/conversations/v0.13/twilio-conversations.min.js"></script>
<script src="inviteAccepted1.js"></script>

<script>
    var accessToken = "Token from twilio";
    var accessManager = Twilio.AccessManager(accessToken);
    var client = Twilio.Conversations.Client(accessManager);

    // Begin listening for invites to Twilio Video conversations.
    client.listen().then(function() {
      client.on('invite', function(invite) {
        invite.accept().then(onInviteAccepted);
      });
    });
</script>
```

**remote.php**

```
<div id="remote" style="display:inline-block;"></div>
<div id="local" style="display:inline-block;"></div>
<script src="https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/common/v0.1/twilio-common.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/conversations/v0.13/twilio-conversations.min.js"></script>
<script src="inviteAccepted1.js"></script>

<script>
    var otheruser = "local username";
    var accessToken = "Token from twilio";
    var accessManager = new Twilio.AccessManager(accessToken);
    var client = new Twilio.Conversations.Client(accessManager);
    client.inviteToConversation(otheruser).then(onInviteAccepted);
</script>
```

**inviteAccepted1.js**

```
function conversationStarted(conversation) {
  // Here is where you add your own custom functionality.
  console.log('The conversation has started.');
}
function onInviteAccepted(conversation) {
  conversation.localMedia.attach('#local');
  conversation.on('participantConnected', function(participant) {
    participant.media.attach('#remote');
    conversationStarted(conversation);
  });
}
```

Following https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/03/chrome-vs-firefox-webrtc-stats-api-with-twilio-video.html article but getting **conversation._dialogue is undefined error**.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

[The blog post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/03/chrome-vs-firefox-webrtc-stats-api-with-twilio-video.html) you mention is out of date now I'm afraid. Twilio Video (at the time of writing) is in beta and the API has updated to use a new rooms model. Check out the [getting started article on Twilio Video here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/getting-started).

In answer to your question though, [the blog post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/03/chrome-vs-firefox-webrtc-stats-api-with-twilio-video.html) itself never mentions the property `conversation._dialogue`. It refers to `conversation._dialogs` though. So perhaps that's what you are missing.